# Any Android Intent to make SIP Call?

Tags: android, android-intent, sip, telephony, sip-server

Can any body suggest me, any Android Intent to make SIP Call? or even third party framework/lib/app, which has the facility to be invoked using an intent and some parameters will be fine.

Kindly Note: Not regular phone call, needed intent for SIP/Internet Phone call.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Do you mean you want to implement a SIP app?
Then, check this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

Make you app and listen to ACTION_CALL.

Or

2) Do you want to invoke a calling app?
Then the usual ACTION_CALL will do.
(For example, in my phone ACTION_CALL will prompt me if I want to use Skype or Phone App)

Added:
I am using SipDroid in one of my phone. This is what happens when I try to make call:
[image]

Comment: Let me check usual ACTION_CALL. Do you know any SIP Android client apps? TX.

Comment: Updated my answer. I am using SIPDROID client. It will prompt you when a make call intent is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you meant to create an `Intent`, you could trying looking into declaring a custom `scheme` within an `IntentFilter` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, such as calling an `Intent` with a `sip:<numberToCall>` will open your Activity.